# Polymer Components duplicating CSS libraries?

Tags: html, css, polymer

When building web components with [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/) if I include an the same external script/css url (think bootstrap) in multiple web components the browser will make multiple requests to the same URL.

The script/css file does get cached in the browser but is this any different than using vulcanize to concat and inline the files and just serving one file with duplication?

e.g.

**File 1**

```
<polymer-element name="el-name">
  <template>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
</polymer-element>
```

**File 2**

```
<polymer-element name="el-name-again">
  <template>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    ...
</polymer-element>
```

**File 3**

```
<link rel="import" href="file1.html">
<link rel="import" href="file2.html">
```

This will make 2 requests for `bootstrap.min.css` would that be different than just vulcanizing file 3?

Comment: if less repeated code is ultimately downloaded, then that's better. there are other factors though, like repainting upon css arrival once vs twice, css parse times for big files, http caching in-place, etc.

Comment: @dandavis: If I was to remove all of the unnecessary CSS selectors from the Vulcanized file do you think that'd be better than requesting the full CSS lib multiple times (even though there are cache hits and there would still be duplication)?

Comment: sorry, but it really depends on too many things to say y/n. the vulcanized file provides a single point to optimize/min/gzip, and if you can do that, you'll have lower client CPU/time than several redundant files. however, its faster to download two 200kb files than it is to download one 400kb file, unless your page is already loading 5+ resources from the same server, in which case your piplines are full, and larger files would work better. in short, try both ways on a variety of devices, cache and no cache, and pick the winner objectively for your particular site/page.